# Non-static error, can't find reason

Tags: c#, foreach, while-loop

I'm getting an "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property Skirmer_Final.Nyhed.FK_Nyhed_ID.get" error. And I can't figure out whats wrong.

My code

```
public class Nyhed
{
    public int FK_Status_ID { get; set; }
    public int FK_Nyhed_ID { get; set; }

    public static List<Nyhed> GetByStatus(int ID, SqlConnection connection)
    {
        List<Nyhed> result = new List<Nyhed>();

        using (var command = new SqlCommand("Select FK_Nyhed_ID from Status_Kan_Se_Nyhed where FK_Status_ID=@id"))
        {
            command.Connection = connection;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", ID);

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Nyhed StatusKanSeNyhed = new Nyhed();
                    StatusKanSeNyhed.FK_Status_ID = ID;
                    StatusKanSeNyhed.FK_Nyhed_ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    result.Add(StatusKanSeNyhed);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
            foreach (Nyhed N in result)
            {
                N.status = Status.GetByID(FK_Status_ID, connection);
                N.nyhed = Nyhed.GetByID(FK_Nyhed_ID, connection);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Can you see the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FK_Nyhed_ID` is a property.  As such, you need to reference it through an object.  I'm guessing the problem is here:

```
foreach (Nyhed N in result) {
    N.status = Status.GetByID(FK_Status_ID, connection);
    N.nyhed = Nyhed.GetByID(FK_Nyhed_ID, connection);
}
```

You previously referenced `FK_Nyhed_ID` on the `StatusKanSeNyhed` instance, so I'm guessing you'll want to reference `N.FK_Nyhed_ID` below

```
foreach (Nyhed N in result) {
    N.status = Status.GetByID(FK_Status_ID, connection);
    N.nyhed = Nyhed.GetByID(N.FK_Nyhed_ID, connection);  //<----- added object reference
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the you wanted to write

```
        foreach (Nyhed N in result)
        {
            N.status = Status.GetByID(N.FK_Status_ID, connection);
            N.nyhed = Nyhed.GetByID(N.FK_Nyhed_ID, connection);
        }
```

and add the missing `N.`

Comment: How did I missed that. Feeling like a dumm now

Answer (score 0):

`FK_Status_ID` is an instance property so it cannot be accessed from a static method.
You can either make it static or change your method to an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
foreach (Nyhed N in result)
        {
            N.status = Status.GetByID(FK_Status_ID, connection);
            N.nyhed = Nyhed.GetByID(FK_Nyhed_ID, connection);
        }
```

You are trying to read public member FK_Status_ID, whitch is accessible only though an instance of an object.